# Get event object from SequenceWaiter

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit

When I add SequenceWaiter step into the SequenceRunner, how can I get event object which was passed into the event? There is the code from my test function:

```
var sequence: SequenceRunner = new SequenceRunner(this);
sequence.addStep(new SequenceCaller(manager, function(): void {
    manager.startUpload();
}));
sequence.addStep(new SequenceWaiter(manager, PackageUploadEvent.BEFORE_PACKAGE_UPLOAD, 1000));
sequence.addStep(new SequenceCaller(manager, function(): void {
    // TODO: Get event object from PackageUploadEvent.BEFORE_PACKAGE_UPLOAD event
}));
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it. Have you tried asking the FlexUnit forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on [flexunit forum](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3430868#3430868). The basic idea is to extend `SequenceWaiter` class, override `setupListeners` function to set up additional event listener and save event object to the public field in this listener.